# Autofill a word.docm file using python

Tags: python-3.x, ms-word, docx, python-docx, word-automation

I am trying to auto-fill a word.docm file using python.
I could find solution to automate word.docx filling. But with word.docm files, the code fails.

This is how the sample 'template.docm' file looks like.[image: sample docm image] 
I need to fill field1 and field2 from python.

I am attaching the code,that worked perfectly for docx files. Can anyone please suggest any edits or any other method that works for word.docm files using python?
Thanks in advance

```
from __future__ import print_function
from mailmerge import MailMerge
from datetime import date

template = "template.docm"
document = MailMerge(template)
print(document.get_merge_fields())
document.merge(field1='Name',field2='Address')
document.write('template-output.docm')
```

Comment: very basic comment: syntax error at `document.merge(field1:'Name',field2:'Address')` (should be `=` instead of `:`). The modification is too small so StackOverflow won't let me edit it. Can OP edit this ?

Comment: @CédricVanRompay - This code works only for word.docx files. My requirement is  to  auto fill word.docm files

Comment: Can you explain *how* it "doesn't work"?

Comment: @CindyMeister . The result values are not getting filled in the respective fields in the output file. I am getting only the input file as such as output file.